# WCF: use or not to use exception from service to client in production? any alternative?

Tags: wcf, exception

I am thinking in use some exceptions to from service to client.

I am thinking for example in this case. The client try to insert a register in the database. This register has a value for e filed that exists in the database, and how it has a unique constraint, when I do the savechanges I get an updateException.

I am thinking to use exceptions (faultException) to warn to client of the error, and use a custom class to send to the client the actual data of the register, so in this way the client does not to make other query for the register.

However, in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms752208.aspx), it says that exceptions only should be used in development, no in production, so, without exceptions, how could I do what I want to do?

Perhaps I could use a custom class, that have one list property for each type of entities, and a property bool, that indicates if the operation is right or wrong, other property with an arbitrary code to indicate the type of error... etc. This is a good alternative?

In summary, really is better avoid exceptions in production? how I could communicate to the client errors from the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- Throw exceptions and return WCF faults
- Attach error information to you return objects

I personally favour throwing exceptions and returning WCF faults. I dont like the idea of attaching error information to return objects, I feel it violoates object oriented principals. For example a field called 'ErrorCode' has no place on a 'CustomerAddress' object.

I believe that if exceptional circustances arise, then an exception should be thrown. This will also simplfy your code as you wont have to wrap everything in try catch blocks in order to attach error information to your return object. Although you may want to catch unexpected exceptions and then throw a more appropriate exception with a more useful message.

Comment: I have the same idea, if in the exception use a class that have a minimal information, I think that it could be more unsafe than a global class with state information. But always is good to have other points of view. Thanks.